# Upgrading WSP using Powershell

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2010

I've run the `Update-SPSolution` command which I am guessing has worked as I have no errors returned. However, my extra feature in the WSP file doesn't show in the site collection features.

I've never really upgraded a solution I've always done the long winded retract it all and then reinstall. This is possibly down to my lack of understanding and I have been told upgrading can be sketchy by several people I have worked with.

How come the extra feature hasn't shown up in my collection features?

Does the upgrade solution only replace the WSP file and then you need to run the install command again?

If anyone could point out some decent articles on this it would be hugely appreciated.

I have managed to get the feature installed by re running the install solution powershell command and it seems to have worked!

However is this best practice? I can't see any detrimental affect of doing it this way currently!

Comment: In my expriences and i am sure somewhere in the docs, you can only do an update on a solution that has the same ammount of features and files, otherwise you need to do a full retractions and add/install dance.

Comment: I did the upgrade, then i ran the install solution and the new feature went straight in! I'm not sure if anyone can point out if this is bad practice and why?

Answer (score 3):

You would need to run the Install-SPFeature command after the Update-Solution to install the newly added feature. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607825

Comment: I will have to test this another time! This sounds like it would work. I re ran the install solution after the upgrade and it seemed to work a treat

Answer (score 1):

From my experience I use Update-SPSolution only when I need to deploy an updated dll for the whole existing solution (wsp). 
If you updated other files or added a new feature then these changes will not be available, as update doesn’t instantiate manifest file to make your new feature available.

To "really" update solution you need to write an "UpgradeActions" as described here.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee535723.aspx

Comment: This is a follow-up to the comments above. When you use Install-SPSolution, it will activate features again. Make sure that feature that you are re-activating don’t do anything destructive ( delete/create lists etc). There are only two proper ways to upgrade a solution: Update-SPSolution with "UpgradeActions" or a new solution with different dll version and feature names. Otherwise on Install-SPSolution you will override what was installed by that feature previously.